# I'm facing an issue while trying to install the bcrypt.js package using Node.js version 14

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

when I try to install bcrypt version 5 or below ,it not install for Node.js version 14. It show error like this:

```
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for bcrypt@5.1.1 and node@10.19.0 (node-v64 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '//node_modules/bcrypt/build'
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.4.0-56-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/node-gyp" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=//node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node" "--module_name=bcrypt_lib" "--module_path=//node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3" "--napi_version=5" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=3" "--node_napi_label=napi-v3"
gyp ERR! cwd //node_modules/bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v10.19.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v6.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/bin/node /usr/bin/node-gyp configure --fallback-to-build --module=//node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=//node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3 --napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=3 --node_napi_label=napi-v3' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.cmd.on (//node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:89:23)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 5.4.0-56-generic
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "//node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd //node_modules/bcrypt
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v10.19.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.11
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute '/usr/bin/node /usr/bin/node-gyp configure --fallback-to-build --module=//node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=//node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3 --napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=3 --node_napi_label=napi-v3' (1)
npm WARN argus_sv2@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN argus_sv2@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.3 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! bcrypt@5.1.1 install: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@5.1.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! /root/.npm/_logs/2024-01-02T08_19_53_217Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Which operating system and version?

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/wiki/Installation-Instructions?

Comment: i use this method but it does not work on windws 10 also ubuntu server

Answer (score 0):

Try run
`npm install --global --production windows-build-tools` for windows
`sudo apt-get install -y build-essential python` for ubuntu

Try reading https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/wiki/Installation-Instructions too

Comment: its not working om windows10